# Would this function work for generally sanitizing db query variables?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection, sanitization

I know most people say to just use prepared statements, but I have a site with many existent queries and I need to sanitize the variables by the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function method.

Also the php manual of `mysqli_query()` says `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is an acceptable alternative, so here I am ...

I want to do this type of queries:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = %s", 
                    query_var($user_name, "text"));
$Records = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

I want to know below function would work, I am unsure if:

- I should still do the `stripslashes()` at the start ? An old function I used from Adobe Dreamweaver did this.
- Is it OK to add the quotes like `$the_value = "'".$the_value."'";` after the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ?
- Does it have any obvious / big flaws ?

I noticed the `stripslashes()` removes multiple `\\\\\\` and replaces it with one, so that migt not work well for general use, e.g when a user submits a text comment or an item description that might contain `\\\\`, is it generally OK not to use `stripslashes()` here ?

I am mostly worried about SQL injections, it is OK if submitted data included html tags and so, I deal with that when outputing / printing data.

```
if(!function_exists('query_var')){
    function query_var($the_value, $the_type="text"){
        
        global $db;
        
        // do I still need this ?
        // $the_value = stripslashes($the_value);
        
        $the_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $the_value);
        
        // do not allow dummy type of variables
        if(!in_array($the_type, array('text', 'int', 'float', 'double'))){
            $the_type='text';
        }
        
        if($the_type=='text'){
            $the_value = "'".$the_value."'";
        } 
        
        if($the_type=='int'){
            $the_value = intval($the_value);
        }
         
        if($the_type == 'float' or $the_type=='double'){
            $the_value = floatval($the_value);
        } 
        
        return $the_value;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're worried about SQL injection, why aren't you using query parameter binding? It's easier and more secure, and you don't need to ask if your function is sufficient. You don't need a function.

Comment: Because the site has over 1000 queries with 4-5 lines each. I cannot rewrite them all, they already contain `sprintf()` and a function that sanitizes the variables, I just need to fix the function to work with existent queries. I also don't find the PDO way very readable, the way it ads the variables and their type. Maybe for a new site I would use PDO.

Comment: You don't have to use the type. In the MySQL PDO driver, they all bind as strings anyway. You can just pass an array to the `execute()` function.

Comment: The variable type must have a purpose, I imagine `x > 10` is different than `x > '10'` I didn't test PDO very much thou.

Comment: Well, if you read the code of the MySQL PDO driver, you'll find that they are passed as strings regardless. The type argument to `bindParam()` or `bindValue()` is ignored (except for types NULL and BLOB). So passing an array of PHP scalars to `execute()` is just fine, and you can use either strings or integers. The driver figures it out. I'm always puzzled by how many PHP developers think they must use `bindParam()` for every PDO prepared query. Apparently they didn't read the code examples on https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I sure need to look more into PDO, and I understand it is the new standard to do things, but for this existnet site, I still need to sanitize the variables by function :/

Comment: All I'm saying is that I'd convert the code to use PDO, and I'd rewrite the queries to use parameters. Even though there are 1000+ queries, that's honestly not that much work, compared to worrying about the security of your sanitize function. I'd be surprised if it takes two weeks of focused work.

Answer (score 0):

A text string constant in MySQL / MariaDB starts and ends with a single quote `'` character. If the text itself contains a quote character, we escape it by doubling it. So the name "O'Leary" looks like this in a SQL statement's text.

```
SET surname = 'O''Leary'
```

That's the only rule. If your users feed you data with backslashes or other escaping schemes, you can feed it verbatim to MySql with the kind of text string representation mentioned here.

Don't overthink this. But use carefully debugged escaping functions. Avoid writing your own, because any tiny bug will allow SQL injection.

Comment: You meant `SET surname = 'O\'Leary'` there ? I a still unsure if I should do `stripslashes` before `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: I meant doubling the single quotes. Backslashes inside MySql string constants are just backslashes.

Comment: Now I am even more confused :/ Are both `''` and `\'` accepted and do the same ? When I insert a value `O'Leary` from phpMyAdmin it sets the query to this and it works: `INSERT INTO 'test' ('name') VALUES ('O\'Leary');`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the PHP functions documentation, I found some references that made me decide the `stripslashes()` is not needed in that function.

[https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

> Generic functions like addslashes() are useful only in a very specific
> environment (e.g. MySQL in a single-byte character set with disabled
> NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES) so it is better to avoid them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

> The addslashes() is sometimes incorrectly used to try to prevent SQL
> Injection. Instead, database-specific escaping functions and/or
> prepared statements should be used.